# Dismiss a VC and return to a countdown on previous VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

How can I get a VC to dismiss while returning to the previous VC which still displays the state after the START button was pressed (ie buttons still visible and countdown still going on etc.) as in this snippet.

```
 -(IBAction)startPressed:(id)sender
 {
// hide start UI
self.startButton.hidden = YES;
self.promptLabel.hidden = YES;

// show running UI
self.timeLabel.hidden = NO;
self.distLabel.hidden = NO;
self.paceLabel.hidden = NO;
self.stopButton.hidden = NO;
self.progressImageView.hidden = NO;
self.mapView.hidden = NO;
self.cameraButton.hidden = NO;

self.seconds = 0;

// initialize the timer
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(eachSecond) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

self.distance = 0;
self.locations = [NSMutableArray array];

[self startLocationUpdates];
```

}

Currently the previous VC returns to the initial state with all buttons hidden and the START button ready to press again.

What kind of segue to the second VC is necessary so the countdown on the first VC continues and the second simply appears over it and is then dismissed without interfering with the stuff going on on the first one?

Comment: If i understand clearly. you need a call back to your first VC to do some action from second VC, In that case, you can use any callback method like a delegate, block or notification.

Comment: No, nothing that happens on the second VC has anything to do with the countdown on the first. It's a camera to take a snap before going back to the first VC which should still be counting down. If that makes sense. I just need the second VC to dismiss while going back to the first VC which is still doing its thing.

Comment: what am suggesting is "you can send message from second VC to first one to change the UI(like show the button) & continue the timer".

Comment: Ah ok, I get you now. Not sure how to do that, am quite new at this, though that's something else for me to investigate, thank you.

Comment: Would something like this solve my problem if I can work out how to implement it? Or maybe use the unwind segue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514270/saving-or-returning-to-previous-ios-scenes?rq=1

Comment: Yes, you can use any of these pattern(like delegate, notification, unwind etc). I would suggest you to use unwind segue or delegate. any of these two is most suitable for your problem. Good Luck!!